# script not working on Ajax-loaded Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jquery powered voting system, and the items on other pages are loaded via ajax, but on ajax-loaded contents the jquery voting needs the page to be refreshed for the vote to be processed.

http://ohmygosh.vr.lt/

I think the problem is within the actions in this [file](http://ohmygosh.vr.lt/init.min.js.php) (?) But i'm not really sure. I don't have any code to start since I don't even know where to start. How do I fix this Problem?

Comment: You need to use "live" instead of click, since click is only bound to the current DOM, not new elements - where LIVE binds to all elements. Do you have a link to an uncompressed version? :)

Comment: Here's the content of the php file: http://pastebin.com/MAaW4ypz

Comment: The new jQuery 1.7 "on()" method is preferable to ".live()", but ".live()" would work.

Comment: Seems thats not the problem.. :(

Comment: I tried replacing it with live but didn't fix it :(

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery not working in Ajax load page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117421/jquery-not-working-in-ajax-load-page)

Comment: nope, delegate doesn't neither :(

Comment: Just to test, could you try using live on the submit too? `$forms.live('submit',function()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that you are using a SmartAjax to load the page content. What SmartAjax does is that it changes the page url (using pushState or hash), loads data and REPLACES the content of #posts div with the loaded content.

The problem is that you are listening click events from DOM elements which are later deleted and replaced with new DOM elements. Thus, the click events from the ajax loaded content are not listened. [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) doesn't help in this case.

To fix this, you have at least these two options:

1) Use jQuery's [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to attach the handler and use #posts div as the root element, since it remains after the new content is loaded.

Something like this should work:

```
$('#posts').delegate(':input', 'click', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert('You have clicked thumbs up/down, value: ' + value);
    return false;
});
```

2) Add click listener to the loaded items after data loading is completed.

Notice: Starting jQuery 1.7 you should use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Comment: @rap1ds Hi Thanks for answering, where should i be inserting that code? `http://ohmygosh.vr.lt/custom.js`

Comment: With that piece of code you should be able to replace the current click event binding, basically this code block: $forms.find(':input').click(function() { ... });